# Improve jQuery performance - should window.location.href be variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

We have search results on our website and want to display different banners based on the search term entered. My solution for this is to check the URL for the search term since it is stored there, and then display the banner if there is a match.

As a result, I have about 20 conditions in an if statement and I think this is slowing down my search results.  Is there a way to achieve this with better performance? Should I store each URL string I want to check for as a variable instead?

```
    if((window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=Palm&shopBy=color") > -1)){
            $("#palm").show();
        }
        else if((window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=Mineral+Blue&shopBy=color") > -1)){
            $("#mineral-blue").show();
        }
        else if((window.location.href.indexOf("searchTerm=Sisal&shopBy=color") > -1)){
            $("#sisal").show();
        }
```

Also, I had this inside a ready event but according to [this article](http://www.upgradetheweb.com/2014/04/jquery-performance-optimization/), it would be faster to leave it out of .ready. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Measure the options and see if you can find any difference. If you can, do the better performing one; if you can't then don't care

Comment: That code is definitely _not_ what's slowing down your page load/render time. A bunch of `indexOf` calls on strings that are probably 100 characters long take milliseconds to run. Use a profiler (Chrome, Firefox and IE>10 have pretty good ones built in).

Comment: Also not using `$(document).ready` is not an option for you because you _need_ the DOM to be completely loaded if you intend to manipulate it with that code, and you are doing just that.

Comment: All the above examples have `shopBy=color` is that always the case? or is it a combination of both for each?

Comment: @GaryStorey it isn't always the case, I just didn't want to put all 25 examples in the post. Most of them have that but there are usually some outliers

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the `searchTerm` then how about this?

```
$(function() {
  var oGetVars = {};

  if (window.location.search.length > 1) {
    for (var aItKey, nKeyId = 0, aCouples = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&"); nKeyId < aCouples.length; nKeyId++) {
      aItKey = aCouples[nKeyId].split("=");
      oGetVars[decodeURIComponent(aItKey[0])] = aItKey.length > 1 ? decodeURIComponent(aItKey[1]) : "";
    }
  }
 //Javascript
 if (document.getElementById(oGetVars.searchTerm.toLowerCase()) {
   document.getElementById(oGetVars.searchTerm.toLowerCase()).style.display='block';
 }
 //jQuery
 $('#'+oGetVars.searchTerm.toLowerCase()).show();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the second answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript (Don't forget to up vote them if it helps you)

The example in that answer uses this library http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/;

Basically what you'll want to do is parse out the query string once; get the values of `searchTerm` and `shopBy` then put them into a variable.

Then instead of doing `indexOf` every time you can just check the values of the two variables you've created. If you are doing a lot of URL manipulation/querying using a helper library can save you lots of time.